# Authorization in CAS VS WSO2 benefits

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, wso2-identity-server

I know that Jasig CAS Single Sign on solution has no Authorization built-in but some other solutions such as WSO 2 comes with this feature.I think I can manage Authorization for my applications with using attribute release feature in Cas and Or using One centered LDAP directory application such as Active Directory or ApacheDS.Why Solutions like WSO2 offers this feature and what is benefits of having Authorization in your SSO solution?I like to know any benefits of WSO2 over CAS.

Answer (score 0):

CAS server 4.x has authorization built in.